# Find an element of vector which is presented in the map

Tags: boost, bind, std, c++

I need to find an element of vector which is presented in map. Hard part is that vector consists of structures, so you should call member function to extract value form the structure first to compare it to the map elements.

So, with for cycle it's pretty easy:

```
vector<A>::iterator it;
for( it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it )
{
    if( mp.count( it->getKey() ) )
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

My question: is there any way to do it in one line, something like

```
//this doesn't work as count accepts key_type
vector<A>::iterator it = find_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost::bind( &map<string, string>::count, mp, boost::bind( &A::getKey, _1 ) )) != 0);
```

Full example, to test

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A( const std::string& key )
    : key( key ) {}

    std::string getKey(){ return key; }
private:
    std::string key;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    map<string, string> mp = boost::assign::map_list_of( "Key1", "Val1" ) ( "Key2", "Val2" ) ( "Key3", "Val3" );
    vector<A> vec = boost::assign::list_of( "AAA" ) ( "Key2" ) ( "BBB" );

//    vector<A>::iterator it = find_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost::bind( &map<string, string>::count, mp, boost::bind( &A::getKey, _1 ) )) != 0);
    vector<A>::iterator it;
    for( it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it )
    {
        if( mp.count( it->getKey() ) )
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << ( it != vec.end() ? "found" : "not found" ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution was close, there is just one closing parenthesis too many.  Placing each parenthesis on a newline with indenting for each level emphasizes the invalid parenthesis:

```
vector<A>::iterator it = find_if
(
  vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost::bind
  (
    &map<string, string>::count, &mp, boost::bind
    ( 
      &A::getKey, _1 
    )
  )
) // one too many
!= 0);
```

In its simplest form, the line becomes `iterator = find_if(...) != 0)`, which will cause the compiler to fail on either:

- Not being able to find `operator!=(iterator, int)`.
- The `)` token in `!= 0)`.

With correct parentheses, `!= 0` uses an operator overload provided by `boost::bind`.  The line would look like:

```
vector<A>::iterator it = find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
  boost::bind(&map<string, string>::count, &mp,
              boost::bind(&A::getKey, _1)) != 0);
```

---

However, consider the readability of such a simple operation.  If a simple `for` loop is not generic and reusable enough, then consider hiding it within a convenience function:

```
template <typename InputIterator,
          typename C,
          typename Fn>
InputIterator find_if_contains(
  InputIterator first,
  InputIterator last,
  const C& container,
  Fn fn)
{
  while (first != last)
  {
    if (0 != container.count(fn(*first))) return first;
    ++first;
  }
  return last;
}

...

vector<A>::iterator it = find_if_contains(
   vec.begin(), vec.end(),
   mp, boost::bind(&A::getKey, _1)
);
```

Otherwise, a custom predicate type may enhance readability while providing some extra flexibility for reuse with different types.  For example, consider the following predicate type that works for various types of associative containers:

```
template <typename C,
          typename Fn>
struct contains_predicate
{
  contains_predicate(const C& container, Fn fn)
     : container_(&container), fn_(fn)
  {}

  template <typename T>
  bool operator()(T& t)
  {
    return 0 != container_->count(fn_(t));
  }

  const C* container_;
  Fn fn_;
};

template <typename C,
          typename Fn>
contains_predicate<C, Fn>
contains(const C& container, Fn fn)
{
  return contains_predicate<C, Fn>(container, fn);
}

...

vector<A>::iterator it = find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
  contains(mp, boost::bind(&A::getKey, _1)));
```

Comment: Hi, this works. I believe problem was not in number of braces, but in ...  &mp ... where I missed the &.

Comment: @Alex: Glad it works for you.  The difference between passing `mp` by value instead of by a pointer is just an optimization, as `mp` can be copy-constructed.  The problem is the extra parenthesis.  [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b2a625da792e0c3b7e7b203b9053ca65-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59) online compiler fails because it could not find `operator!=` taking an iterator (the return from `find_if`) and int (`0`).  Removing the extra parenthesis causes `!= 0` to use a `boost::bind` operator overload, rather than trying to compare against the return from `find_if`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, use a lambda:

```
find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](A const & a){return mp.count(a.getKey());});
```

But since you're using Boost.Assign rather than uniform initialisation, perhaps you can't do that. I'm afraid I don't know how to construct a functor like that using `bind` alone.

Comment: I wish I could. However I'm using previous version of C++.

Comment: @Alex: In that case I'd stick with a `for` loop. Even if you do find a suitable `bind` expression, it will be far less readable.